# Rename a large number of files

Tags: r, rename

I'm trying to rename a large number of .jpeg files:

```
EH574_54340_TopX0_TopY0_W850_H500
EH574_54340_TopX0_TopY500_W850_H500
EH574_54340_TopX0_TopY1000_W850_H500

EH574_54505_TopX0_TopY0_W850_H500
EH574_54505_TopX0_TopY500_W850_H500
EH574_54505_TopX0_TopY1000_W850_H500

EH574_54610_TopX0_TopY0_W850_H500
EH574_54610_TopX0_TopY500_W850_H500
EH574_54610_TopX0_TopY1000_W850_H500
```

to EH574Sub1 to EH574Sub8779. There are 8,779 files in that folder.

I've tried

```
file.rename(list.files(pattern="EH574_*.jpeg"), paste0("EH574Sub", 1:8779))
```

but the error returned was

> Error in file.rename(list.files(pattern = "EH574_*.jpeg"), paste0("EH574_",  : 'from' and 'to' are of different lengths

Can I please get some help here?

Comment: The asterisk is NOT a regex wildcard! Try '.+'

Comment: I'm on Win 7. So do you mean try pattern = "EH574_.+"???

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
file.rename(list.files(pattern=glob2rx("EH574_*.jpeg")), paste0("EH574Sub", 1:8779))
```

You need to convert the pattern to a regular expression using glob2rx.

I have fixed the error.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried the code but got this error message: Error in file.rename(list.files(pattern = glob2rx("EH574_*.jpeg"), paste0("EH574Sub",  :  argument "to" is missing, with no default